# Run windows in vm actually bad for your ssd?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, adobe-photoshop

I try to figure out a work arround using Windows as my main os, I do prefere Fedora linux, I was wondering if running Windows and photoshop in a vm is a good thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

No, not with modern SSDs.

Once upon a time, SSDs did not last as long as HDDs. Now, they do. [PC Magazine said](https://www.pcmag.com/article/297758/ssd-vs-hdd-whats-the-difference) in January 2019: *Longevity: While it is true that SSDs wear out over time (each cell in a flash-memory bank can be written to and erased a limited number of times), thanks to TRIM command technology that dynamically optimizes these read/write cycles, you're more likely to discard the system for obsolescence (after six years or so) before you start running into read/write errors with an SSD. If you're really worried, several tools can let you know if you're approaching the drive's rated end of life. Eventually, hard drives will wear out from constant use, as well, since they use physical recording methods. **Longevity is a wash when it's separated from travel and ruggedness concerns**.*

Comment: Meh. Six years is *nothing* unless you've been suckered into the expensive throwaway culture! I ain't throwing anything away in six years' time just because six years have passed.